# SQLite query help needed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am displaying client info in a listView in which it only displays clients with a bill entered into the database like so.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM clients" +
                " WHERE LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLONE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTWO + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTHREE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLFOUR + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill');";
```

and now i am trying to add a search functionality to the listView where the user can type in any part of the clients name or address like so.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM clients" +
                " WHERE LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLONE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTWO + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTHREE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLFOUR + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') AND" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_NAME + ") LIKE LOWER('%" + inputText + "%') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_ADDRESS + ") LIKE LOWER('%" + inputText + "%');";
```

and this work half the time. The time it works is when you only type in a letter that is in a name and not an address. But if you search any part of an address itll not only show the clients with bill but clients with out bills enter as well.

How can i change my query statement to only show the clients with a bill entered when the user searches a name or address in one query?

***EDIT***

i have just noticed that when i type in a name the search functionality does not filter the names either!

***EDIT***

ill include some pictures for the search results here

[image: before search results]
[image: after search results]

and here is the search functionality working when you take out the bill part of the query
[image: before search]
[image: after search]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the aditional bock after the `AND` between brackets "`()`". In that way when any of the two last conditions are true, the block after the and will be true.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM clients" +
                " WHERE LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLONE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTWO + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTHREE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLFOUR + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') AND" +
                " (LOWER(" + COLUMN_NAME + ") LIKE LOWER('%" + inputText + "%') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_ADDRESS + ") LIKE LOWER('%" + inputText + "%'));"
```

Comment: ok great! you have solved half of it! thank you! so now the clients without bills do not show up upon search, but the clients with bills are not being filtered by the search.

Comment: so you fixed my initial problem of clients with no bills entered in showing up in the listView upon the search. But now the search is not filtering out and clients at all. if i have a client named billy and a client named maddy and i search the name billy, both clients will still show up.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You would like to see the results of the first of the queries, but when someone types text into the search you would like to see the results of the second query. Is it like that?

Comment: i added some pictures to help clear up the situation. so now it isnt searching correclty.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to juan who lead me in the right direction by putting () around half the query! all i had to do to fix the other problem was put () around the other half like so!

```
query = "SELECT * FROM clients" +
                " WHERE (LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLONE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTWO + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLTHREE + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_BILLFOUR + ") NOT LIKE LOWER('bill')) AND" +
                " (LOWER(" + COLUMN_NAME + ") LIKE LOWER('%" + inputText + "%') OR" +
                " LOWER(" + COLUMN_ADDRESS + ") LIKE LOWER('%" + inputText + "%'));";
```